# data not passing between view Controllers cannot solve

Tags: objective-c, null, push, segue

I am attempting to pass a string between two view controllers, the first named DetailController and the second VideoController. They are connected with a button using a push segue. My "prepareForSegue" method is being called, however the string is returning as null in VideoController. I have been stuck on this problem for ages and still cannot find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

DetailController.m prepareForSegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{   NSString *myString=self.city.camera;
    NSLog(@"%@", myString);
    NSString *see=@"what is going on?";
    NSLog(@"%@", see);

    VideoController *video= (VideoController *) segue.destinationViewController;
    video.cam= self.city.camera;

}
```

VideoController.m

```
#import "VideoController.h"
#import "City.h"
#import "DetailController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface VideoController ()

@end

@implementation VideoController
@synthesize webView,city,cam;



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *see = self.cam;
    NSLog(@"%@", see);

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    [self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:10.0];





    NSString * html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img name=\"Cam\" src=\"%@\" width=\"110%%\"  height=\"100%%\" alt=\"Live Feed\" style=\"background-color: #000000\" />", cam];

    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

}
-(void)yourMethod
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

here are the messages that I am receiving when the button is pushed and the segue takes place. If I am reading it correctly the (null) is being returned by the same webView as the other two strings when it should be coming from within a different webView? I am totally lost with this problem

```
2014-04-21 02:20:23.093 webView[47963:1a303] http://admin:*******@192.168.1.80/video.cgi/
2014-04-21 02:20:23.094 webView[47963:1a303] what is going on?
2014-04-21 02:20:23.102 webView[47963:1a303] (null)
```

Here is my VideoController.h file, as you can see sam is set to strong, am I missing something?

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailController.h"
@class City;
@interface VideoController : UIViewController{
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
IBOutlet UIImageView *image;



}
@property (strong,nonatomic) City *city;
@property (strong, nonatomic)NSString * cam;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *webView;


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

See my comment:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{   
   NSString *myString=self.city.camera;
   NSLog(@"%@", myString);
   NSString *see=@"what is going on?";
   NSLog(@"%@", see);

   VideoController *video= (VideoController *) segue.destinationViewController;
   // be sure that self.city.camera is has value 
   // I think you assign nil to video.cam
   video.cam= self.city.camera;
}
```

Comment: yes self.city.camera does have the correct value since NSString   *myString=self.city.camera;
   NSLog(@"%@", myString); is returning the correct string

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your "cam" property doesn't have a weak attribute assigned, or it may be released before you want. Better yet, post your VideoController.h code.

Comment: I have posted my VideoController.h code, as you can see it is set to strong. Is there something else that I am missing?

Comment: After over a half-hour struggle, I am still unable to re-create your bug. Whatever crazy thing I do to the code, the "cam" data passes just fine and gets logged correctly. You might wanna "clean" and re-build, or close and relaunch your Xcode, or restart your Mac.

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts I cannot see why I would be getting this bug either. I will continue working on it to see if I can solve it.

Comment: I do have another view controller that is the first view in my storyboard, detail controller is actually the second view which takes the "city" information from the first view controller. Is it possible that the way I push detail controller from the first view controller is effecting the passing of data between DetailController and VideoController?

Comment: No it shouldn't, as you already showed it was getting logged correctly. The problem is in the segue from detail VC to video VC. Is it a custom segue by the way or a modal segue? I'm thinking that maybe causing the strange behavior.